# Plotting 3D Grid Data in Python

Tags: python, 3d, datagrid

I am struggling with plotting the following dataset (image below). The dataset represents 10 rectangular features in 3D space. Those features are spaced at a distance of 3 cells in the Y axis. The X and Z columns present the range (number of cells) in the X and Z axes. The output should be 10 rectangles spaced at every 3 cells in Y direction. The rectangles can be in any color.

Another piece of infomraiton (not sure if it's relevent), the number of cells in X, Y, Z directions are 50 cells. Each cell represents a 100 ft distance in real life.

I tired numpy.meshgrid, but with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the corner points of your rectangles - this is fairly straight forward - it's just the 4 combinations of the 2 (x, z) corners, with all of the points having the y-value shown.

The rectangles can then be plotted as:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Corner points of rectangles
feat1 = [(7,6,10),
         (7, 6, 20),
         (13, 6, 20),
         (13, 6, 10)]

feat2 = [(2,9,13),
         (2, 9, 17),
         (18, 9, 17),
         (18, 9, 13)]

feat3 = [(7,12,10),
         (7, 12, 20),
         (13, 12, 20),
         (13, 12, 10)]

features = [feat1, feat2, feat3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

facets = Poly3DCollection(features)
facets.set_facecolor(['blue', 'green', 'red'])
ax.add_collection3d(facets)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Which returns a plot like:
[image]

Comment: kabdulla many thanks for your attempt to answer the question. The real life dataset has more than 400 features. It would be over kill to construct manually the four corner points. Can we arrive to more efficient solution, by breaking the dataset into more columns:
Label, X-begin, X-end, Y, Z-begin, Z-end

Comment: I'm sure you could - but it depends what format your data currently is in. You have provided an image of a table of the data. If this is all you have you will first have to use optical character recognition to get it into a more sensible format - for example https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/

Comment: I see you defined the corner points manually. This not feasible when you have high number of features. Is there away to iterate through the table to create those corner points? The table is in excel format.

Comment: I defined the corner points manually because you shared an image of your input data which isn't a useful starting points. The steps you'll need are: (1) Import data from excel into python, (2) Extract corner points. (3) Plot rectangles (an example above). Good luck!